# curl NSS Error -12156 ssl connect error

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl

I'm seeing the following error while running cURL on an AWS server:

`curl -v --insecure --disable-epsv -l ftps://foo.com/ --user "foo:bar"`

```
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS error -12156
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

It is very similar to this error: [curl: (35) SSL connect error](https://serverfault.com/questions/606135/curl-35-ssl-connect-error) but the error code is `-12156`. I can't seem to find any information about this error code within the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/SSL_functions/sslerr.html

Has anyone seen this error or can direct me to documentation that would give me more details about the error code?

Comment: I don't know that error, but I would try to get a network trace (probably tcpdump) and look at it, and/or try connecting with `openssl s_client ... -starttls ftp -debug` which prints out nearly everything it does.